# Dump hash in columns

Tags: formatting, hash-map, perl

I tried to answer the question ["How to print a hash in Perl, such that 3 key value pairs are printed on each line?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31444449/603855) like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31447384/603855).

As I got an uncommented downvote, I'd like to ask: What's wrong with/How to improve:

```
use Modern::Perl;

my %h = ();
for (0..7) {
    $h{$_} = chr(65 + $_);
}
print %h, "\n";
my $cols = +$ARGV[0] || 5;
my $n = -$cols;
for my $key (keys %h) {
    print $key, ' => ', $h{$key}, 0 == ++$n % $cols ? "\n" : "\t\t";
}
print $n % $cols ? "\n------" : "------";
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Wrong` is too heavy word, and I don't why it get down voted, but minor improvements are possible.

- `Modern::Perl` is not core module and it usually means `strict`, `warnings`, and perhaps `autodie` are used (plus some other tweaks).
- `chr()` is not needed, and hash slice assignment works equally well, not to mention that it is perl idiom
- `keys %h` may generate large in memory list for bigger hashes, and `while .. each` handles such cases better. There is a catch with `each` as it uses internal hash pointer which needs to be reset with `keys %h` if you want to start back from hash beginning (in `non LIST` context `keys %h` doesn't generate list).

---

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %h;
@h{ 0 .. 7 } = "A" .. "H";
my $cols = 3;
my $n = -$cols;

keys %h;
while ( my ($k,$v) = each(%h) ) {
  print "$k => $v";
  print 0 == ++$n % $cols ? "\n" : "\t\t";
}
print "\n" if $n % $cols;
print "------";
```